# Can :xdo_user_name be used in list of value in Oracle bi publisher? Or just works in data set

Tags: oracle, bi-publisher

I am making a data mode. Involve a list of values to bind with parameter. Just want to ask if adding :xdo_user_name as the list of value sql parameter is possible?

I am hoping that user login， the menu will only show related data to him.

Many thanks.

Not sure if this can work or not.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a List Of Values - Type SQL Query

```sql
select :xdo_user_name as USER_ID from dual
```

Now create new parameter of (parameter) type Menu and based on the above LOV. Next, in your datamodel you can use the newly created parameter any way you need.